# CGI script not able to create and append a file to specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, cgi

I'm writing a CGI script in SHELL that reads information from the QUERY_STRING and then creates a .student file with that information (ID, name etc). When I try to create and/or append to this file, I'm unable to create it, or move it to my database directory. It works perfectly fine to create the file within the cgi-bin directory that I'm working in, but if I try to mv it, it doesn't work.

Both the cgi-bin directory, and the database directory have permissions of 0777.

Here's the code I want to work:

```
echo "Student_ID=${Student_ID}" >> ~/public_html/database/${Student_ID}.student
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the permission for that specific file?

Comment: I've tried going as far as giving that file 0777 when creating it locally, and then using mv to try and move it to the database directory. No luck though.

Comment: What SO and version? SELinux enabled?

Comment: like @Joao suggested: post Operating System and version. SELinux is most likely culprit.  `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory exists, and the user has sufficient permissions. Check the process exit status(`$?` variable). Log the errors to a reliably writable place.

```
dir="$HOME/public_html/database/"
db_file="${dir}/${Student_ID}.student"
error_log=/tmp/cgi-error.log

# If $dir doesn't exist
if [ ! -e "$dir" ]; then
  # Create $dir path
  mkdir -p $dir
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to mkdir $dir" >>"$error_log"
    exit 1
  fi

  chmod +wx $(dirname $dir) $dir
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to set permissions for $dir" >>"$error_log"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

if [ ! -w "$db_file" ]; then
  echo "$db_file is not writable!" >>"$error_log"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Student_ID=${Student_ID}" 2>>"$error_log" >> "${db_file}"
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to log $Student_ID to $db_file" >>"$error_log"
  exit 1
fi
```

Also, avoid `0777` permissions. At least, you don't need `w` permissions for "others", unless it's a `/tmp`-like directory which has its [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) set: `1777`.